# Calculation between two query result Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet collecting bet results

| Date | % investment | odds | won |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 | 2 | 1.12 | yes |
| 01/06/2021 | 2 | 1.09 | no |
| 02/06/2021 | 3 | 1.05 | yes |

I thought creating query filtering if the bet has been lost or won could help but I am stuck

```
=QUERY(bets!A1:D;"select A, sum(B), sum(C), count(A) where D = 'yes' group by A")
```

With that I can have the victories with the some summary day by day.
But this is not really what I want.

But the result I want is more complex
The initial bankroll amount is 100
The result should be

| Date | invested % | invested amount | output | bankroll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 | 4 | 4 | 0.24 | 96.24 |
| 02/06/2021 | 3 | 2.89 | 3.03 | 96.38 |

I do not know if I can do that with Google Sheet formulas, or I will need to use a script.

Comment: Welcome. Please excuse my naivety regarding gaming. Are you using "decimal" odds? So, a winning wager of $2 at odds of 1.12 would yield $2.24: being the original $2 stake plus $0.24 profit. A losing wager of $2 at odds of 1.09 would yield a loss of $2 being the original stake. Regarding the bankroll, does this include wining stakes or only profits/losses? Based on results for 1/6/2021, the closing bankroll would be $100 plus $2.24 less $2.00 which equals $100.24; however your closing bankroll is $96.24.  Would you please explain the difference.